# Add or remove elements based on checkbox status using react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple section in which contains products with multiple checkboxes and default prices,
I want when the checkbox is true to show its price and remove all the rest pricess obvious those with the false state. if all checkboxes are false then show all the prices

Live demo : [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-agnesi-rfnui?file=/src/App.js)

Here is what I have so far //toppings.js

```
export const toppings = [
  {
    name: "Capsicum",
    price: 1.2
  },
  {
    name: "Paneer",
    price: 2.0
  },
  {
    name: "Red Paprika",
    price: 2.5
  },
  {
    name: "Onions",
    price: 3.0
  },
  {
    name: "Extra Cheese",
    price: 3.5
  },
  {
    name: "Baby Corns",
    price: 3.0
  },
  {
    name: "Mushroom",
    price: 2.0
  }
];
```

Here is my solution

```
import { toppings } from "./utils/toppings";

export default function App() {
  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(
    new Array(toppings.length).fill(false)
  );

  const handleOnChange = (position) => {
    const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
      index === position ? !item : item
    );

    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);

    const elements = updatedCheckedState.filter((currentState, index) => {
      if (currentState === false) {
        delete toppings[index].price;
      } else if (currentState === false) {
        toppings[index] = toppings[index].price;
        console.log("current state", currentState);
      }
      return 0;
    });
    console.log(elements);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul className="toppings-list">
        {toppings.map(({ name, price }, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              <div className="toppings-list-item">
                <div className="left-section">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}
                    name={name}
                    value={name}
                    checked={checkedState[index]}
                    onChange={() => handleOnChange(index)}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}>{name}</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <ul className="toppings-list">
        {toppings.map(({ name, price }, index) => {
          return <li key={index}> {price} </li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately this is not working as expected, can someone tell me what am doing wrong here

Comment: You're both deleting the price properties altogether, so you won't be able to retrieve them, and also mutating state with your `filter()` call. If you don't want to show price of checked items just do it conditionally in the render. Also don't use `index` as [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: you should create a re-usable component to show checkbox and price then, handle toggle by an internal state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple working example.
storing all selected item indexes in a state array

Live example -
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-sara-t5ws3?file=/src/App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { toppings } from "./utils/toppings";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);
  const handleChecked = (e, index) => {
    let prev = checked;
    let itemIndex = prev.indexOf(index);
    if (itemIndex !== -1) {
      prev.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    } else {
      prev.push(index);
    }
    setChecked([...prev]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul className="toppings-list">
        {toppings.map(({ name, price }, index) => {
          return (
            <>
              <li key={index}>
                <div className="toppings-list-item">
                  <span className="left-section">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}
                      // name={name}
                      // value={name}
                      checked={checked.includes(index)}
                      onChange={(e) => handleChecked(e, index)}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}>{name}</label>
                  </span>
                  {(!checked.length || checked.includes(index)) && (
                    <span>{price}</span>
                  )}
                </div>
              </li>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```